# How do I do this transformation in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I forgot what it is called, but I need to do the following transformation in Pandas:

I have:

```
[Name, address, phone, IDnum]
[John, Doe lane, xxxx, A111]
```

and I want:

```
[Name, data_type, value] 
[John, address, doe lane]
[John, phone, xxxx]
[John, IDnum, A111]
```

I know there is an easy way to do this, I just forgot.

Comment: `melt`: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for pandas.melt

```
# Create the dataframe
df=pd.DataFrame(data=
    {
        'Name': ['John'], 
        'address': ['Doe lane'],
        'phone': ['xxxx'],
        'IDnum': ['A111'],
     })
df

# Apply melt
pd.melt(df, id_vars=['Name'], ignore_index=True)

# Result
```

| Index | Name | variable | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | John | address | doe lane |
| 1 | John | phone | xxxx |
| 2 | John | IDnum | A111 |

You can also set the dataframe equal to the result if you need to call it again

```
df_melted = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['Name'], ignore_index=True)
```